# Turning off Snowflake telemetry

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, telemetry

I'm trying to turn off Snowflakes client telemetry and found this document:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Connectors-or-Drivers-fail-due-to-invalid-client-telemetry-snowflakecomputing-com-Certificate

There are two options described the latter which offers what seems to be a SQLish:

```
ALTER USER TESTUSER SET CLIENT_OUT_OF_BAND_TELEMETRY_ENABLED=FALSE PARAMETER_COMMENT='disabling due to JDBC issue' PARAMETER_EXPIRY_DAYS=0;
```

What I'm unclear on is where is one supposed to run this script. I've tried **snowsql** and the web interface to no avail:

> invalid property 'PARAMETER_EXPIRY_DAYS' for 'USER'

Comment: I have been doing some checking and that parameter appears to be settable only internally (meaning, by Snowflake). You will need to open a case with Support to have them do that. I will request that the `ALTER` statement as shown in that article be corrected since it gives the impression it can be set by customers.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I will open a ticket.